# Unfortunately your app has stopped working

Tags: java, android, crash

I made an app with minimum API level of 18 but it says something like:

> Unfortunately Your app has stopped

While running in android 4.4 Emulator but runs perfectly fine on 6.0 emulator.

> 09-16 01:51:20.995 2579-2579/com.neupane.kugeclass E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.neupane.kugeclass, PID: 2579
>                                                                        android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020055
>                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:321)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:114)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:206)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:182)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:192)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:451)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1138)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:91)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:229)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:284)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1030)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1053)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:460)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the folder in which you have put the drawables. By mistake you have put the drawables-v21 folder which is not picked by below 21. That is why it is working on marshmallow but not on kitkat. Resource is not finded by system. Check it once and let me know

Comment: yeah i found the the drawables are put in 21 folder but dont know how to change C:\Users\dines\AndroidStudioProjects\KUGEClass2\app\src\main\res\drawable-v21

Comment: put the images in res\drawable folder then it ll work

Comment: Kindly accept the answer as accepted and upvote this answer if it wokrs